# edit custom content in bigcommerce stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

As we're currently moving from Blueprint to Stencil, we would like to add some blocks of custom content to our home page.

A block of custom content would contain an image, a line of text, as well as a link to a product, a brand, or a page.

1. Is there a way to add a text block (text input field) in the Stencil Theme Editor in order to edit a line or block of text (besides just (background) colors, image size dropdown, etc.) without having to upload a new version of the theme?
2. An option would be to use the language file (en.json) to store the content. Is there a way to modify the en.json file without having to upload a new version of the theme for every update?

Or, is there another way to deal with custom content blocks in Stencil?

To give more context, the user/client should be able to replace a background image, (promotional) content, links etc. through the Theme Editor without  having to "hand-code"... to make it more like a WYSIWYG "WordPress"-style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem we first encountered was that the option "Edit Theme Files" from within the Theme Editor didn't do anything.

The answer to the problem is to go to "Storefront Design" > "My Themes" > "Edit Theme Files".
This option opens up the editor allowing us to edit the "en.json" file that contains the actual content for the handlebars we added to the html file.